# In ZK how to show html contents in a label?

Tags: java, html, ckeditor, zk

Can any one tell me how can i show HTML contents with the help of ZK label? Like if i have text something like this

```
<b> this is my test message </b>
```

Then i have to show this content in page with bold ..

**this is my test message**

Comment: you can only use setStyle attribute I think. Consider using div (display:inline) and append a html object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if the following example will help you..

```
<window id="win" title="Html Demo" border="normal">
    <html><![CDATA[
        <h4>Hi, ${win.title}</h4>
        <p>It is the content of the html component.</p>
    ]]></html>
</window>
```

Here they are using **html** tag inside window to show the text with html tag.

Comment: Hi Subodh, windows have children html but lable do not have children html. how to define  lable in html contents.